# ‘pescatarian’: synonyms & etymology

Tags: meaning, etymology, orthography, food

Even if most Americans would take ‘[pescatarian](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pescatarian)’ to be some odd Calvinist sect, according to Merriam-Webster it is a noun which means “one whose diet includes fish but no other meat” and its derivation is “probably from Italian *pesce* fish (from Latin *piscis*) + English *vegetarian*”.

**Questions**
 **1.**  It is clear that some people will understand the  term simply by recognising its roots; however, is there a well-established word — having an analogous meaning — that sounds less awkward than *pescatarian*? I'm looking for a word that is commonly understood among Anglophones, not only those who belong to strict circles and follow dietary ‘experimentalism’ culture?

**2.** Can anyone give more precise information or any reference about its origin?

**3.** Is there some reason as to whether one would prefer spelling it as ‘pescetarian’ rather than ‘pescatarian’?

Comment: This is the first word I've ever heard for fish-eaters, I don't think there's a well-established, common word for it.

Comment: _Pescetarian_ (my preferred spelling, though both exist and are used) **is** a well-established, common word. It's not awkward at all, and I would say it is in general quite well understood among Anglophones.

Comment: Not a single word but would be commonly understood: "I don't eat animals other than fish"

Comment: @Janus [GoogleNgrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pescatarian%2Cpescetarian%2Cvegetarian&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvegetarian%3B%2Cc0) and I beg to differ. There are very few groups I'm familiar with that wouldn't think 'pescatarian' ridiculously high-falutin (if they even thought it was English).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Possibly we just move in different circles. Being myself a vegetarian, I have been aware of the word, and used it as a natural part of my vocabulary, for over a decade. I have come across people who didn't know what it means, but they frequently didn't know what _vegan_ and sometimes even _vegetarian_ means, either. I would never consider it high-falutin’. I would not expect it to show up in Ngrams before around 2008, though, which as far as I know is the most recent year you can search for.

Comment: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pescetarian) says that the first known use is in 1993. That also argues against it being well-established (although there are obviously newer neologisms that have taken hold, e.g. many words related to the Internet and cellphones).

Comment: @Barmar It's a recent word, but then the very concept is fairly recent in mainstream culture. Dietary ‘experimentalism’ is mostly a notion that did not exist in the general public’s awareness just 20 years ago, beyond a vague notion of vegetarianism. These days, completely ‘average Joe’ types often know what it means to be pescetarian, lacto-ovo, vegan, and even raw vegan and fruitarian—it's become a popular trendy thing to _be_, not just know. They're all hipster words, but they're common enough in colloquial speech—at least, they're more common than any other terms for any of those things.

Comment: I think most people would understand the word simply by recognizing the roots. But I don't think you can honestly argue that it's anywhere near as commonly used or heard in popular culture as _vegetarian_ or even _vegan_. Since you're a vegetarian, you probably encounter media that refers to these concepts much more than most people.

Comment: @Barmar Not media, no. But the topic probably pops up in conversation more for me than for most others. Out of the three, _pescetarian_ is the least common, yes; but I come across more people who know what it is than people who don't, even among people who are not vegetarian or anything like that.

Comment: Most Americans would take _Pescatarian_ to be some odd Calvinist sect.

Comment: @John Lawler: As I would, if I saw it spelled as the OP has it.  Now if it was 'piscitarian', I would recognize it immediately as a cognate of 'piscivore', from the Latin for "fish eater".

Comment: I believe that I invented the word in 1994 as part of a catering training course I wrote and presented to chefs embarking on a career working in Mediterranean summer clubs and Alpine ski resorts. I wanted to define the type of food culture surrounding European seaside resorts, which is predominantly a mix of fish and vegetables, and created the noun pescatarian for ease of reference. As I learnt to speak Portuguese in Brazil, this had a nice ring to it and was immediately identifiable to anyone with a knowledge of languages of a Latin origin. Not to mention much easier to pronounce that my Ang

Comment: Considering that the word was in use at least three years before your training course, I find it doubtful that it is of your invention; or perhaps rather that yours was the original invention of it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I wasn’t aware of that—I won’t fret too much about it, then, and will keep that in mind. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: I'm with Barmar, Janus, et al. How does pescatarian differ from vegetarian or, come to that, carnivorean, please?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Usage and alternative words

A simple answer to this one: **no**, there is no word for pescetarians that is more commonly used or understood than *pescetarian* (or *pescatarian*, if you prefer that spelling).

It is not a concept that has been spoken about commonly for very long, and *pescetarian* is, to my knowledge, the only word for it that has any practical currency at all. It is not overly common, but it is also not limited to “strict circles”. It is not uncommon for average people (with no special dietary habits) to know at least more or less what a pescetarian is.

A perhaps more transparent alternative is *pesco-vegetarian*, which more overtly marks the connection between pescetarianism and vegetarianism. It may be easier for people who do not know what pescetarianism is to grasp the meaning of *pesco-vegetarian*, but it is not in as common use as *pescetarian*.

At least equally common as *pescetarian*, though, is misuse of the term *vegetarian*. By any commonly accepted definition, a vegetarian does not eat any kind of meat, including poultry and fish; but quite a few people do not consider fish and/or poultry ‘meat’ and thus do not distinguish vegetarians and pescetarians (and often not vegans, either).<sup>1</sup> It is my personal experience, however, that the percentage of people who use *vegetarian* to refer to pescetarians is decreasing. Ten or 15 years ago, nearly everyone thought people who only ate fish were vegetarian; nowadays, the split between those who call it *vegetarian* and those who call it *pescetarian* is more like 50/50. (Excluding of course the ones who do not know that there is a term for either thing, which these days is a definite minority.)

Your best bet is to simply get used to *pescetarian*, even if you do think it is awkward, because there is no better alternative. Alternatively, if you want to make sure you’re understood and don’t care it’s a bit longer, explain: “I tend towards vegetarianism, but I do eat fish as well” or something like that.

## Origin of the word

#### The established theory

As both Merriam-Webster, Wikipedia, and the OED mention, the formation of the word is not quite clear. The second element, *-tarian*, is clear enough: it originated in *vegetarian*, whence it spread to other types of ‘dietary lifestyles’. *Vegetarian* is itself a more or less ad-hoc blend of *vegetable* (or possibly *vegetation*) and the weakly productive suffix [*-arius*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-arian).

The first element is more difficult to track down. It is quite obviously the word found in Latin *piscis* and Italian *pesce*, both meaning (and cognate to) ‘fish’—but its form and pronunciation doesn’t really match anything.

Italian *pesce* has the /e/ of *pescetarian*, but ⟨sc⟩ before a(n orthographic) front vowel represents /ʃ/ in Italian, and *pesce* is phonetically [ˈpeʃe]. This is different from English where *pescetarian* is generally pronounced /pεskɨtεəriən/<sup>2</sup>, with /sk/.

In Classical Latin, ⟨c⟩ always represented /k/, and *piscis* was phonemically and phonetically [ˈpiskis]; in later Latin as well as in English words derived from the Latin word, however, ⟨sc⟩ represented first the /ʃ/ of Italian and later on (in French, where English got most of her Latin words from) a simple /s/. Thus for example the Zodiac sign *Pisces* is /ˈpaɪsiːz/ in English, not */ˈpɪskiːz/ or anything like that. On the other hand, there are English words derived from the Latin word where the ⟨sc⟩ appears before a back vowel, in which case the pronunciation never changed and is still /sk/ in English. There are such words in Italian as well, where the Italian /e/ is maintained—but not in English.

The OED has a total of 43 words beginning with *pisc-* (excluding two for the liquor known as *pisco (Collins)*, which is named after a Peruvian city whose name, [according to Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pisco#Etymology), is from Quechua and thus unrelated). Of these 43 words, 26 begin with *pisce-* or *pisci-* and thus have no /k/ sound, while 16 begin with *pisca-* (14), *pisco-* (1), or *piscu-* (1). The *pisco-* and *piscu-* words (*piscose* and *pisculent*) are both marked as obsolete as are two of the *pisca-*, so basically, there are a handful of words beginning in *pisca-*, all pronounced /ˈpɪskə-/.

Contrarily, there is only **one** word in the entire OED beginning in *pesc-*, and that is *pescetarian*.

Both Merriam-Webster and the OED agree that in *pescetarian*, the first element is “probably” taken from Italian, but they cannot really explain why the word has /sk/ in English. The [OED article](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/407463) says:

> If the assumption that the word was formed on Italian *pesce* is correct, the pronunciation with /sk/ (rather than /ʃ/ ) and the spelling *pescatarian* both suggest that this origin has been opaque to many from an early date.

#### An alternative theory

Personally, I would suggest a slightly different scenario:

I believe the word was originally coined not from Italian, but from Latin, and I would hypothesise that whoever first came up with it in the late 1980s or early 1990s actually started out with **piscatarian*, to go with adjectives like *piscatorial* (‘of or concerning fishermen or fishing’). Since the coinage was so obviously meant to be a ‘spinoff’ of *vegetarian*, though, the vowel structure of *piscatarian* was adapted to fit that of *vegetarian*; thus (showing only the vowels with “.” as the syllable separator):

> *vegetarian* /ε.ə.ˈεə.iə/
>   *piscatarian* /ɪ.ə.ˈεə.iə/ ⇒ /ε.ə.ˈεə.iə/

Once the word started gaining popularity and entering wider usage, it was already *pescatarian*, and the link to the Latin root *pisc-* was somewhat tenuous and strained. Tenuous enough, at least, that people with limited knowledge of Italian started connecting the word to the Italian word *pesce* (often seen on menus in Italian restaurants) instead of the Latin root, and also began spelling it like the Italian word.<sup>3</sup>

The hypothetically ‘original’ spelling *piscatarian* (as well as *piscetarian*, of uncertain pronunciation) have appeared here and there in the early days; but they are far less common than the forms with ⟨e⟩.

## Spelling preference

As for why one would prefer one spelling over another—well, that’s just personal preference. I personally prefer *pescetarian* because it maintains the same vowel skeleton as *vegetarian* not only phonologically, but also orthographically (and preferring in general British orthography, words like *sceptic* mean that I don’t find ⟨sce⟩ pronounced /skε/ all that unacceptable). One may equally prefer *pescatarian* because it is more intuitive for the ⟨c⟩ to represent /k/ before ⟨a⟩ than before ⟨e⟩ (especially if one generally prefers US orthography, where *skeptic* is not a parallel for ⟨sce⟩ as /skε/).

---

## Notes

1. There is an awful lot of variation between who considers what ‘vegetarian’ and ‘non-vegetarian’. At one end of the spectrum are those who cling to the very narrowest possible definition of vegetarianism: someone who does everything they can to avoid eating, consuming, or otherwise using any part of an animal whose extraction directly or indirectly impacts the animal negatively: meat, skin, leather, ivory, etc. At the opposite end are those who call themselves vegetarian because they don’t eat red meat but do eat pork, poultry, fish, seafood, etc. I would say there is some leeway in how strict you need to go (I have no problem with calling someone who uses regular soap or wears leather shoes a vegetarian), but once your diet starts including the meat from animals, there’s little point left in terming it ‘vegetarianism’ anymore.
2. I’m using [Wikipedia’s IPA notation for English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_English) to indicate phonemic writing here.
3. I imagine someone with *proper* Italian skills would not have done this, since they would be familiar with other Italian words that have [pesk-], like the verb *pescare* [pesˈkaːɾe] ‘to fish’. Assuming *pescetarian* is an urban American invention, though, most people who might use it are relatively likely to know *pesce* from restaurants, but less likely to know any other Italian words from the same root.

Comment: *Piscivorous, ichthyophagous*. :)

Comment: @tchrist One of those means something else; the other I'm not sure about, but it's definitely not more common than _pescetarian_! ;-)

Comment: [Piscivores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piscivore) are mainly fish-eaters.  [Ichthyophagi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichthyophagi) are from Herodotus. But it might be a hard one to sell to get somebody to call themselves a piscivore or an ichthyophag**e**. Both sound like something they’re not.

Comment: @tchrist A piscivore is any animal whose diet consists mainly of, and is based on, fish. Most piscivores, like most carnivores, do not really eat plants. Pescetarians are a different kettle of, erm, fish-eaters, since they are usually primarily herbivores who add fish into their diets. Based on the Wikipedia page, _ichthyophagous_ seems to be more pescetarian than piscivore—but most of all, it is of course extremely obscure, far more than either of the two others.

Comment: I don’t think obscurity of the term will protect you if you call someone an *icthyophag* without the *-e*. :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "One of those [_piscivorous, ichthyophagous_] means...": which one means what?

Comment: @Mitch _Piscivorous_ means something different from _pescetarian_ (as detailed in my next comment): it refers to animals who eat fish-based diets, rather than humans who choose not to eat meat. The difference is analogous to _vegetarian_ vs. _herbivorous_.

Comment: I agree with *nearly* everything except for this part: *nowadays, the split between those who call it vegetarian and those who call it pescetarian is more like 50/50.* Do you have any facts that back this figure? Because in my experience, the term pescatarian is much less common than vegetarian.  I meet far fewer people who think chicken can be included in a vegetarian diet,  whereas many still believe a diet that includes the occasional fish dish is neither hypocritical nor contradictory.

Comment: Perhaps this is an Italian thing... but I'd wager this is common in many parts of the UK (not so in London where being a "foody" is very trendy.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, no, no facts—as I said, it's just my own personal experience. And it is probably significant that my own personal experience is from living in a capital, not out in the countryside. I imagine my experience would be different if I weren't in a big city.

Comment: I would have imagined a *piscatarian* were a sea monster that preyed on fishermen. :) Also, your inclusion of pork in the diets of those who eschew “red” meat surprises me: isn’t all mammalian flesh deemed “red” meat by definition? I may have to confess to some ignorance in this, however, as I’ve not eaten such things during your lifetime, and perhaps terms shift around in meaning. Or are you alluding to the old joke about German vegetarians being permitted only one pork chop per meal? :)

Comment: @tchrist That too depends. I’ve been told that if you ask someone from Argentina, you’re most likely to hear that only beef (preferably steak) is meat. There are lots of people who consider pork and (at least some types of) venison to be white meat, though. The [Wikipedia article on white meat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_meat) even has a little note about pork and the controversy over what is and isn’t white meat.

Comment: Oh wait, **Argentina**?  Well sure: in Spanish, to speak of *carne* without qualification virtually always means *carne de vaca*, leading people to understand a(n over-)literally translated *no como carne* as *no como carne de vaca*. But that, I think, is a separate problem. Growing up amongst hunters around the Great Lakes, I never heard anyone refer to venison as somehow being “white” meat. Then again, menus often separate “meat” from “fish” and sometimes from “poultry”, just as they sometimes bundle molluscs and crustaceans with “fish”. Food words are weird.

Comment: @tchrist True—but there are quite a few Anglo- and other -phones that share the Argentinians’ view on this. Even in hipster European cities, it’s not **that** uncommon to hear people say things like “But fish/chicken/rabbit/horse isn’t meat!” or “But pork isn’t red!”. They’re usually thoroughly trounced by more sensible people (read: me), but they still pop up now and again. ;-)

Comment: Europeans often have bizarre ideas about meat; I blame popery. [“Rabbit was a favorite of of French monks, because they considered them fish and could eat them when abstinence from meat was called for.”](http://www.foodreference.com/html/frabbit.html)

Answer (score 7):

To answer your first question, I have recently heard people introduce themselves as being [*fishetarian*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=fishetarian&oq=fishetarian&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.1225.4817.0.5100.14.9.1.4.5.0.187.841.5j3.8.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..2.12.687.0.LMjPT_7Ef8U).

It seems to be something of a neologism but it is certainly clearly understandable.

Comment: I have heard of fishetarian, so +1. I wouldn't say it's as common as pescetarian though, and (personally) I know enough languages to know that pesce = fish.

Answer (score 5):

The earliest match that I could find in a Google Books search for the exact spelling *pescatarian* is from DeCherney, DeCherney, Marshall & Brook, [*The Fiddlehead Cookbook: Recipes from Alaska's Most Celebrated Restaurant and Bakery*](https://books.google.com/books?id=XDG32mYhUMoC&pg=PA12&dq=%22pescatarian%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOl9PKib3KAhVY02MKHSGgDtI4yAEQ6AEIOTAF#v=onepage&q=%22pescatarian%22&f=false) (1991) [page readable on first view of the link, but not thereafter]:

> Most New England chowders start with bacon or salt pork to give them their distinctive smokiness. In order to please our "**pescatarian**" crowd, we have used Alaskan smoked halibut to give our chowder that ...

The variant spelling *pescetarian* shows up in two Google Books matches from 1995, neither of which reproduces well in the snippet windo of Google Books search results. From Dave Gibbons, [*Using Your Modem: The Fast and Easy Way to Learn*](https://books.google.com/books?id=i4Q4sx3dRGcC&q=%22pescetarian%22&dq=%22pescetarian%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL_pC2j77KAhUK4GMKHRlTA804lgEQ6AEIKDAD) (1995) [combined snippets]:

> I also got some great seafood recipes and found out that a vegetarian who also eats seafood is a "**pescetarian**." Whether you're writing a business report, planning a party (you can find some interesting home-brewed beer recipes online),  trying to settle an argument, or participating in any other information pursuit, you'll get answers a lot quicker online ...

And from Robert Richardson, [*Web Guide*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZEFSBBdKx7IC&q=%22The+site,+part+of+which+is+shown%22&dq=%22The+site,+part+of+which+is+shown%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisw4Owlb7KAhUHxWMKHZLUC8kQ6AEIITAB) (1995) [combined snippets]:

> The site [Vegetarian Pages], part of which is shown in Figure 2.105, also contains a glossary that clears up terms confusing to the nonvegetarian community, such as *vegan* and ***pescetarian***, and pointers to just about every vegetarian resource on the Internet, ...

Google Books does find a significantly earlier match for the variant spelling *piscatarian*. From [*Philosophy East & West*](https://books.google.com/books?id=76cvAAAAIAAJ&q=%22piscatarian%22&dq=%22piscatarian%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwioq5W1j73KAhUB_mMKHXclChI4ChDoAQgyMAQ) (1979[?]) [combined snippets]:

> In terms of the metaphor, Hinduism is not saying that eggs, vegetables, and meat are all food: it is suggesting that all of them have nutritional value and that one's preference for an item may depend on one's cultural preferences or dietary requirements; and that the vegetarian may not despise the eggatarian or the **piscatarian**—or the other way around.

The extreme outlier in Google Books results is this match for the variant spelling *piscitarian*, from [*Mary Anerly: A Yorkshire Tale*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KPYEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA89&dq=%22piscitarian%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNx-WJkb3KAhVBx2MKHTmJAZsQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22piscitarian%22&f=false), chapter 48, in *Fraser's Magazine for Town and Country* (July 1880):

> So fugitive is vivacious stir ; and so well content is the general world to jog along, in its old ruts. The Flamborough butcher once more subsided into a **piscitarian** ; the postman, who had been driven off his legs, had time to nurse his grain again ; Widow Tapsy relapsed into the very worst of taps, having none to demand good beverage ; and a new rat, seven fold worse than the mighty net-devourer ... took possession of his galleries and made them pay.

Since the primary scientific term all along for "fish-eater" has been *piscivore*, I think that we see with the seemingly unrelated outbreaks of *piscitarian* (starting in 1880), *piscatarian* (in 1979), and *pescatarian* (in 1991) is a series of independent attempts to create a word modeled on *vegetarian* for people whose diets include fish but no other types of meat.